# Surface Integral of a sphere

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I'm studying vector calculus on my own and I got a little confused by the following problem: Let a sphere of radius $r_0$ be centered at the origin, and $r′$ the position vector of a point $p′$ within the sphere or under its surface $S$. Let the position vector r be an arbitrary fixed point P. The integral that I have to solve is as follows:

$$\oint_{s} \frac{1}{|r-r'|}da' $$
$$\rightarrow \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{|r-r'|}r_{0}^2 \hat r \sin{\theta}d\theta d\phi $$
$$\rightarrow 4\pi r_{0}^2 \frac{1}{|r-r'|}\hat r  \qquad(*)$$

And in that part (*) got stuck. I know how to analyze r (inside or outside the sphere), but I couldn't get the expected result. I also tried replacing the unit vector with $\vec r/|r|$. I know the result is:
$$\frac{4\pi r^{2}_{0}}{r} \quad\text{for} \quad r\geq r_0 \quad and \quad 4\pi r^{2}_{0}\quad for \quad r\leq r_0 $$

Answer (score 1):

The integral is independent of $r$ and $r'$. So you can isolate the term,
$ \dfrac{1}{|r-r'|}r_{0}^2\hat r$ and integrate wrt $\theta$ and $\phi$.

$I= \dfrac{1}{|r-r'|}r_{0}^2\hat r\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin{\theta}d\theta \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi=\dfrac{1}{|r-r'|}r_{0}^2(1+1)(2\pi)\hat r=\dfrac{4\pi r_{0}^2}{|r-r'|}\hat r$